# how to focus on the very first element after scroll using mCustomScrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I am using AJAX to bring more data to my `div` and `mcustomscrollbar` to scroll. What I want is as soon as the data is loaded for my `div` to focus on the very element of the loaded data. For example, if the loaded data starts from 6 to 10 so `div` should show the data from 6.
My code reads like this

```
function generatemCustomeScrollbar(elementID)
{
     $(elementID).mCustomScrollbar({
     scrollButtons: {
         enable: false
     },
     theme:"rounded",
     scrollEasing: "easeOut",
     moveDragger: true,
     mouseWheel: {scrollAmount: 200},
     keyboard: {enable: 1},
     keyboard: {scrollAmount: 200},
     keyboard: {scrollType: "stepless"},
     contentTouchScroll: 200,
     scrollbarPosition: "outside",
     alwaysTriggerOffsets: true,
     advanced: {
         updateOnBrowserResize: true,
         updateOnContentResize: true
     }
 });
}
```

I have initialize the scrollbar on document.ready...

```
generatemCustomeScrollbar(".myDiv");
```

and my ajax look like this... it's example

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:base_url+'ajax_more_near_poi',
        dataType:'json',
        data:data_send,
        success: function(data){
        if(data.error_msg){
             $(".myParentDiv").html(data.error_msg);
        }else{
             console.log("success");
             $(".myDiv").append(data.html_detail);
        }
        overloading = false;
        },
        error: function(){
             console.log("error");
             overloading=false;
        }
  });
```

Comment: And where is the data added to the scollbar? This looks like the definition of the scollbar only

Comment: myDiv is the div where I am loading the data through ajax.. like 

$(".myDiv").append("data.myData");

So everytime, I hit the button, data is appended into this div.

Comment: I understand. I asked because basically you want to set the selection of the scollbar in the succes function of you ajax call. The element you want to select is the first element in data.myData, so this is where to find it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply... was in the middle of the something... but i have posted my ajax call.